# PHPUnit call to undefined method `Mock_x_::method()`

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, undefined

I'm trying to create my first phpunit test and find myself needing to stub a method on an `IMailer` interface.

```
interface IMailer
{
    public function send($to, $from, $cc, $subject, $body);
    public function sent();
}

    $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder(
        'IMailer',
        array('send', 'sent'))->getMock();

    $mailer->method('send')->willRreturn(0);
```

However, I keep getting

```
PHP Fatal error: 
  Call to undefined method Mock_Mailer_13fc0a04::method()
  in ...Test.php on line 16
```

a `var_dump($mailer);` results in

```
class Mock_IMailer_4c3e02a7#215 (1) {
  private $__phpunit_invocationMocker =>
  NULL
}
```

Working with the `expect($this->any())` gives a dito error - it seems that the mocked object does not have any mock functionality...

I'm running phpunit 3.7.28, and php 5.5.9, on an ubuntu box.

How come?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

The getMockBuilder function accepts only the className as parameter. The correct way to initialize your mock object methods would be to use setMethods function (see [phpunit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html))

```
   $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('IMailer')
       ->setMethods(array('send', 'sent'))
       ->getMock();
```

Additionally you probably want to have some expects definition also when you use your mock object:

```
   $mailer->expects($this->any())
        ->method('send')
        ->willReturn(0);
```

**EDIT**

The above holds true for newer phpunit versions. For phpunit 3.7.28 the mock object usage is a bit different (i.e. the expects seems to be mandatory and willReturn is not yet available). For 3.7.28 version you should modify the second part to:

```
   $mailer->expects($this->any())
        ->method('send')
        ->will($this->returnValue(0));
```

I would recommend updating to later phpunit version as it seems to be somewhat difficult to find documentation to this much older releases.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my `getMockBuilder` invocation.  However, the `undefined method` remains...

Comment: The above code runs nicely without errors on phpunit 4.1.0. Did you try adding the expects function call to the second part (`$mailer->expects->method->willReturn`)? Could you share the whole test class that you are running? That might give some more clues to the problem you are facing...

Comment: i think this should be accepted answer. ->setMethods and ->returnValue solved my very similar problem (also it seems i have old phpunit)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, for anybody that is still using old versions of PHPUnit, but still wants to be able to call `method()` directly, is to override the default mock object class template.

Copy [`MockObject/Generator/mocked_class.tpl.dist`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/1.1/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator/mocked_class.tpl.dist), and name the copy `mocked_class.tpl`. Then, just add [the code for the `method()` method](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/3.0/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator/mocked_class_method.tpl.dist) to the template:

```
public function method()
{
    $any = new PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_AnyInvokedCount;
    $expects = $this->expects($any);
    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func_array(array($expects, 'method'), $args);
}
```

This will allow you to call `$mock->method()` directly. However, you need to still use `->will($this->returnValue(0))` instead of `->willReturn(0)`. To do that, you need to introduce a custom invocation builder and invocation mocker:

```
class My_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker
    extends PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker {

    public function willReturn( $value ) {
        return $this->will( new PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_Return( $value ) );
    }
}

class My_MockObject_InvocationMocker
    extends PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker {

    public function expects( PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation $matcher ) {
        return new My_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker($this, $matcher);
    }
}
```

And update your template again, to use `My_MockObject_InvocationMocker` instead of `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker`.

The full template would then look like this:

```
{prologue}{class_declaration}
{
    protected static $staticInvocationMocker;
    protected $invocationMocker;

{clone}{mocked_methods}
    public function expects(PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation $matcher)
    {
        return $this->__phpunit_getInvocationMocker()->expects($matcher);
    }

    public function method()
    {
        $any = new PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_AnyInvokedCount;
        $expects = $this->expects($any);
        $args = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array(array($expects, 'method'), $args );
    }

    public static function staticExpects(PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation $matcher)
    {
        return self::__phpunit_getStaticInvocationMocker()->expects($matcher);
    }

    public function __phpunit_getInvocationMocker()
    {
        if ($this->invocationMocker === NULL) {
            $this->invocationMocker = new My_MockObject_InvocationMocker;
        }

        return $this->invocationMocker;
    }

    public static function __phpunit_getStaticInvocationMocker()
    {
        if (self::$staticInvocationMocker === NULL) {
            self::$staticInvocationMocker = new My_MockObject_InvocationMocker;
        }

        return self::$staticInvocationMocker;
    }

    public function __phpunit_hasMatchers()
    {
        return self::__phpunit_getStaticInvocationMocker()->hasMatchers() ||
               $this->__phpunit_getInvocationMocker()->hasMatchers();
    }

    public function __phpunit_verify()
    {
        self::__phpunit_getStaticInvocationMocker()->verify();
        $this->__phpunit_getInvocationMocker()->verify();
    }

    public function __phpunit_cleanup()
    {
        self::$staticInvocationMocker = NULL;
        $this->invocationMocker       = NULL;
    }
}{epilogue}
```